# Memory leak when using Samsung's S Pen

Tags: android, samsung-touchwiz

When touching an S Pen on a view which finishes the current activity, a static View field called `mLastHoveredView` leaks a reference to the view and therefore to its activity context and anything else associated with it.  I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9.7 running 5.0.2.

This field is not present in AOSP and seems to be a Samsung only thing, judging by [this leak canary detection change](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/220), which is unfortunate as it means I can't inspect the source code to see how it is managed.

What would be the best way to handle this?  Using reflection to null the field when finishing the activity seems dangerous.